# Swift app using Stripe - Type 'STPCustomer' has no member 'decodedObject'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate Stripe into an app using the model that they provided in the Swift iOS (Simple) example on their GitHub (Available At: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios).

I added both Stripe and Alamofire to a new project that I am building through Cocoapods, and everything works perfectly excluding one function in the MyAPIClient.swift file. This function is:

```
  @objc func retrieveCustomer(_ completion: @escaping STPCustomerCompletionBlock) {
    let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("customer")
    Alamofire.request(url)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let result):
                if let customer = STPCustomer.decodedObject(fromAPIResponse: result as? [String: AnyObject]) { //Error occurs here      
                    completion(customer, nil)
                } else {
                    completion(nil, NSError.customerDecodingError)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(nil, error)
            }
    }
}
```

On the line including the "if let customer" statement, an error is thrown, explains that Type 'STPCustomer' has no member 'decodedObject'. I am not certain if I added the frameworks incorrectly or did something else incorrectly, as this statement works perfectly in Stripe's swift example project. Here is the entirety of the file in question:

```
import Foundation
import Stripe
import Alamofire

class MyAPIClient: NSObject, STPBackendAPIAdapter {

    static let sharedClient = MyAPIClient()
    var baseURLString: String? = nil
    var baseURL: URL {
        if let urlString = self.baseURLString, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            return url
        } else {
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    func completeCharge(_ result: STPPaymentResult, amount: Int, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
        let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("charge")
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [
            "source": result.source.stripeID,
            "amount": amount
            ])
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseString { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    completion(nil)
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(error)
                }
        }
    }

    @objc func retrieveCustomer(_ completion: @escaping STPCustomerCompletionBlock) {
        let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("customer")
        Alamofire.request(url)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let result):
                    if let customer = STPCustomer.decodedObject(fromAPIResponse: result as? [String: AnyObject]) {


                        completion(customer, nil)
                    } else {
                        completion(nil, NSError.customerDecodingError)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
        }
    }

    @objc func selectDefaultCustomerSource(_ source: STPSourceProtocol, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
        let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("customer/default_source")
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [
            "source": source.stripeID,
            ])
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseString { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    completion(nil)
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(error)
                }
        }
    }

    @objc func attachSource(toCustomer source: STPSourceProtocol, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
        let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("customer/sources")
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [
            "source": source.stripeID,
            ])
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseString { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    completion(nil)
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(error)
                }
        }
    }
}

extension NSError {
    static var customerDecodingError: NSError {
        return NSError(domain: StripeDomain, code: 50, userInfo: [
            NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to decode the Stripe customer. Have you modified the example backend?"
            ])
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm an idiot. Stripe Pushed update 10.1.0, but didn't make the new branch for their 10.1.0 sample project the default one. Everything is golden now.

Comment: I am not sure what fix that you made. Please tell me.

Comment: They have a separate swift example on a branch of their GitHub project that is not the same version as their cocoa pods version.